# Parsing Rails Model Errors in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, coffeescript

I'm trying to parse out validation error messages returned from a Ruby model on the client side, but I am running into problems.

The application returns errors in JSON as expected:

```
"{"error":{"first_name":["can't be blank"],"last_name":["can't be blank"]}}"
```

I cannot figure out how to parse the errors out of the JSON.  I would like to parse out each component pair...i.e. get the field (first_name) and error message ("can't be blank"), but I keep running into errors.

How can i parse these individual pieces out of the response?  I suppose i lack understanding of how to parse the json string into each of its respective components.

I've included the relevant ajax:error function below.  I appreciate any help!  Thank you!

```
$ ->

  $(document).on "ajax:error", "form", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    list_area = $('#error-explanation ul')
    list_area.empty()
    for own key, value of errorList
      console.log "#{key} -> #{value}"
```

The code above outputs to the console:

```
error -> [object Object]
```

I was expecting to see first_name -> can't be blank.  I believe I am not parsing the object correctly.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string. I don't think you want to be doing that. Your data should be (I think) a js object that you can work with directly. BTW, it might be easier/nicer to send back rendered errors html and append that.

Comment: I actually just output the string to see if the correct JSON data was being returned.   As far as the return structure, I have the capability of assigning messages to specific fields (versus one list of all errors).  But I cannot figure out how to parse the json object.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What are you trying?

Comment: I updated the question with my attempt at parsing the json into the respective errors.  I believe I'm one level off on the json object.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved this problem.  I just didn't understand how to get to the nested object in json.

I just needed to point to the correct data in the parsed json object:

```
$(document).on "ajax:error", "form", (event, data, status, xhr) ->

errorList = JSON.parse data.responseText
for own key, value of errorList.error
  console.log "#{key} -> #{value}"
```

Thanks for the response jvillian!